# Auto populate form input based on name?

Tags: forms, grails

If I have a Command Object such as

```
class AppContactInfoCommand {
    String fname = "Tom";
}
```

When I pass that command object to my view to populate my form I have to do this

```
<g:textField name="cmd.fname" value="${cmd.fname}"/>
```

This just seems extremely repetitive and time consuming if I have large forms with many fields.  Isn't there any way to to have the `g:textField` intelligently detect that value and auto-populate the value field so all I have to do is

```
<g:textField name="cmd.fname" />
```

Other frameworks I have worked with do this so Im sure there must be a way from Grails to do this too.

Grails Version: 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from writing your own tag library to do just that. However the included tag libraries for such things as the `textField` do not have this behavior. As can be seen from the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/textField.html).